# Getting permissions of all documents in all subsites from a site using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, permissions, document-set

I am trying to get the permissions users have on each and every document under a specific site collection (e.g. https://test.com)

This is what I tried:

```
function Get-DocumentInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl


foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
    if ($list.BaseType -ne “DocumentLibrary”) {
        continue
    }

foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
$data = @{
            "Web Application" = $webApp.ToString()
            "Site" = $site.Url
            "Web" = $web.Url
            "list" = $list.Title
            "Item ID" = $item.ID
            "Item URL" = $item.Url
            "Item Title" = $item.Title
            "Item Created" = $item["Created"]
            "Item Modified" = $item["Modified"]
            "File Size" = $item.File.Length/1KB
            "Permissions" = $role.Member 
                                }
New-Object PSObject -Property $data
}
}
$web.Dispose();
}
$site.Dispose()
}
Get-DocInventory "https://test.com/" | Out-GridView
Get-DocInventory "https://test.com/" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Users\livob002-lap\Desktop\PermissionTest.csv
```

The `PermissionTest.csv` is created, however it is empty and the GridView does not open.

I am using SharePoint 2013 Collaboration Platform.

I also have full rights/permissions to the servers and farm.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ps code,

```
$data = @{
            "Web Application" = $webApp.ToString()
```

replace `webApp` by `web`

Also, replace the function name to `Get-DocInventory`. It does not match the function calls at the end of the script.

Comment: Thanks! However all the Item Titles are getting shown as `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem`. http://i.imgur.com/ETtEijb.png

Comment: Nevermind, added $item.["Title"] and it worked :) Thanks!